# Invalid length parameter error for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, substring, ssrs-2012

I'm passing a list of names from SSRS to a SQL Server stored procedure but I'm getting an error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

This is my code:

```
Select substring(item, 1, LEN(item) - 36) 
From dbo.fnsplit(@manager, ',')
```

The reason for the substring is to remove a 36 character GUID that is attached to the end of the manager name. The names are passed like this:

```
    John Smith, Tom Perry
```

I've read the error could be caused by spaces, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Do all the names have 36+ characters? I would verify that first. It is possible that one or more are less then 36 and you are removing 36 characters from a string that does not have 36 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `case`:

```
Select (CASE WHEN len(item) <= 36 THEN item
             ELSE LEFT(item, LEN(item)-36)
        END)
from dbo.fnsplit(@manager, ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove last 36 characters from right side in all cases!? So, I think this hack-version should work ;).

```
select 
    replace(item, right(item, 36), '')
from 
    dbo.fnsplit(@manager, ',');
```

> Note: Actually I take 36 characters from right side of text then remove it by replacing with `''` ;).

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6efb9/2)

---

But I think your issue should be something like this:

```
select 
    left(item, abs(len(item + ',') - 37))
from
    dbo.fnsplit(@manager, ',');
```

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6efb9/6)